# How do I correctly use structRef from numba if I only need attributes and no methods?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numba

I am looking into using numba to improve the runtime of the program I have been working on but due to classes I have in my code numba cannot be used as it does not recognize the class types. These classes have no methods and only contain attributes.

I have been looking into structRef [Numba Docs](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extending/high-level.html#defining-a-structref) but I cannot seem to get it to work with a basic example class of just attribues a,b,c,d being initialized as 1,2,3,4.
(Just making this test class usable within njit functions)

```
class values:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a : int = 3
        self.b : int = 4
        self.c : int = 5
        self.d : int = 6
```

Does anyone have an example I can look at?

Comment: Is it not possible to reformulate your problem to use only arrays and functions? That's where you'll get most of the potential speedup.